# Is there a WYSIWYG for rails that allows you to do syntax highlighting for F#?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, f#, tinymce, wysiwyg, tinymce-rails

I'm currently writing a blog web app in rails and ultimately this blog is for me to post about F#. I currently have TinyMCE installed a along with the samplecode plugin found [here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/codesample/). However... after installing it I realized that the TOOLBAR version doesn't support F#.

prismjs does support F# highlighting but TinyMCE does not! Is there a way to support F# in the tinymce drop down?

I do care about others such as Python, C#, Scala but most importantly I need F#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luke -

I work for the company that created TinyMCE.  In order to get Prism to work in TinyMCE's Codesample plugin we had to make a few changes to the Prism.js that is included with TinyMCE.  (Most notably to not immediately try to add its markup to the page)

You could try to generate a new Prism.js file with additional languages and merge in the customizations we made.  You would then update the plugin (and its dialog) appropriately.

The languages you see in the select list are the only ones we provide as a part of the TinyMCE open source product.

Comment: How would you do that? I'm using tinymce-rails gem and I've already uploaded the "new" prism.js and prism.css file. If I were to use <code lang="f#"> it works perfectly fine it's the fact that the drop down literally can't let me select F# when it opens up the text area.

Comment: You have to modify the codesample plugin that is part of TinyMCE.  There is a plugins folder within the TinyMCE distribution and each plugin is in a folder that is the name of the plugin.  There is a Dialog.js file that defines what the dialog looks like (including the select list for languages) and a custom Prism.js file that is used when rendering code samples within TinyMCE.